# Why those Javascript snippets perform the same?

Tags: javascript, performance, benchmarking

```
obj = [1,2,3,4,5];
function iter(){
    for (var key in obj){
        key=key+key;
    };
};
function test1() { 
    iter(obj); 
};
function test2(){
    (function iter(obj){
        for (var key in obj){
            key=key+key;
        };
    })(obj);    
};
```

Here, both test1 and test2 perform the same, even though test2 is supposedly creating a new function everytime it is called. Why?

Comment: How are you measuring the performance of both methods?  What is the accuracy and precision of your measurement?

Comment: @cdhowie I'm measuring the performance by testing how many times each of those functions can be called in 1 second.

Comment: but neither function is *doing* anything...

Comment: @zzzzBov it is calculating 0+0, 1+1, 2+2, 3+3 and 4+4, is not it? I'm not using the result because I just wanted to test if inlining a function like that would hurt the performance.

Comment: I'd think there is a slight difference, but so small it isn't detectable. Also, even though the second test has the extra function, it does get a performance boost by passing `obj` into that function so it is scoped locally instead of globally. Maybe those things offset.

Comment: according jsperf it is not the same http://jsperf.com/why-those-javascript-snippets-perform-the-same but very close for chrome

Comment: @Dokkat, yes, I can read that you're overwriting the `key` variable, but you're throwing out the value without doing anything with it. The test is too simplistic to determine anything.

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: @zzzzBov - The test is aimed at measuring the overhead of function calls, not the performance of the function body. If anything, the function bodies are doing too much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>My guess is that there's no difference in performance because there's no (meaningful) difference in the code. The parser creates the local `iter` function inside `test2` once when it parses the code, not each time `test2` is called. (This isn't like using `eval`.) If anything, the second one will be a tiny bit faster because `obj` is local to the `iter` function.</strike> Well, that was wrong.

As [this jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/explicit-vs-nested-function) shows, the second is indeed slower. You have to be careful about measurement. The way you wrote the functions, the amount of work being done in the function bodies easily masks the difference in function call overhead involved in the two cases. Also, the first case is accessing a global `obj`, while the second is accessing an argument. These differences should be eliminated to, as much as possible, measure only what you're trying to measure. The jsperf test I wrote tries to do just that.

Comment: There are 2 jsperf tests out there contradicting this [here](http://jsperf.com/why-those-javascript-snippets-perform-the-same) and [here](http://jsperf.com/directagainstclosure), but, oh well

Comment: @BeatRichartz - I have [a third one](http://jsperf.com/explicit-vs-nested-function) to break the tie :). The first one is faster in 32-bit IE9, but the second is faster in all the other browsers I've tested.

Comment: ok, but yours is simply about parsing speed because its not executing the functions. If I understood the question correctly, it meant execution speed. Oranges and Apples, I would say. I'm gonna get me an Apple :) No hard feelings!

Comment: @BeatRichartz - D'oh. I updated the test and it is now consistent with your results. In fact, this answer is wrong, so I'd like to delete it (but I can't, since it's accepted). Instead I rewrote it.

Answer (score 1):

I would pretty much guarantee that you will not see the performance difference in only 5 cycles.  In modern JS engines, you will need to test this with iterations in the thousand or even tens of thousands range to actually see the difference.  However, that difference will most certainly show up eventually.

Answer (score 1):

[Your are right, they do more or less perform the same](http://jsperf.com/directagainstclosure)

Your second function, which has a closure in it, has the overhead of creating an anonymous function every time it is called.

In the first one, js can call the function it has already stored.

That leads to the second function being a tiny bit slower.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. If an anonymous function was created every time the second function is called I'd expect a huge performance drop.

Comment: @Dokkat Depends on how you define huge. An average difference of about 15'000 executions per second in chrome is surely notable, in opera and ie it goes well above 100'000. In my eyes, this is not huge, but a pretty big difference.

Comment: Eliminate the function bodies (so you are measuring only the function calls) and they don't perform the same any more.